# Удаление двойных и более слов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не понимаю, я в условие написал {1,} это значит, если повторяется больше одного раза, то это всё удалить, но почему не во всех случаях удаляет?

```
echo preg_replace('#([\w]+)\s\1{1,}#', '$1', 'hello my my  my  my my world');

/hello world world - работает
//hello world  world  world - не работает
//hello world  world  world  world - не работает
//hello hello world - работает
//hello hello hello hello world - плохо работает
//hello my my world - работает
//hello my my my world - плохо работает
//hello my my  my  my my world - hello my my  my  my my world
```

Comment: `\s` - один пробельный символ. у вас встречаются двойные. начните исправление с этого места.

Comment: Все дело в пробелах, вы про них забыли

Comment: `\1{1,}` - находит повторения слова, но без учёта пробелов между ними, т.е. `foo` превращается в найденные `foofoofoofoo`, но не `foo foo foo foo`.

Comment: Добавил проверку на пробелы и всё равно не работает echo preg_replace('#([\w]+)\s+\1{1,}#', '$1', 'hello world  world  world');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#(\w+)(\s+\1)+#
```

`(\w+)` - 1-ая группа захвата, можно сказать что слово, хотя тут можно поспорить; 
`(\s+\1)+` - 2-ая повторяющаяся группа захвата, от которой вы хотите избавиться и состоит она из 1-го или более пробельных символов и слова из первой группы захвата, так как между словами пробелы все-таки должны быть!

Пример https://regex101.com/r/q1OhHr/1

P.S. Можно еще и флаг `i` добавить, чтобы регистронезависимая проверка была и флаг `u` для Юникода.

Comment: оказывается всё так просто

Answer (score 1):

Слово `\w+` и любое число таких же слов с пробельным префиксом `\s+\1` меняем на само слово `$1`. Тесты для самопроверки:

```
$tests = [
    'hello world world' => 'hello world',
    'hello world  world  world' => 'hello world',
    'hello world  world  world  world' => 'hello world',
    'hello hello world' => 'hello world',
    'hello hello hello hello world' => 'hello world',
    'hello my my world' => 'hello my world',
    'hello my my my world' => 'hello my world',
    'hello my my  my  my my world - hello my my  my  my my world' => 'hello my world - hello my world',
];
foreach ($tests as $in => $expected) {
    $actual = preg_replace('/(\w+)(\s+\1)+/isu', '$1', $in);
    assert($expected === $actual, "\n--- {$expected}\n+++ {$actual}\n");
}
```

Если код не вывалил описание ошибок в ассёртах, то всё ОК!